# Is it possible to block functions from compiling by using luajit?

Tags: lua, luajit

So im debugging my lua scripts now, and i here i came to question - is it possible to block function from compiling by using `jit.attach`? (something like this)

```
local function jitcatch(dat)
    local sour = string.sub( jit.util.funcinfo(dat).source, 2 )
    if sour == 'test.lua' then jit.off(dat) end
end
jit.attach( jitcatch, 'bc' )
```

Comment: Note on using StackOverflow: If you put 4 spaces in front of each line of your code rather then the `\`` it will appear in a code block. then it will get syntax highlighting and make it easier to read

Comment: You are attempting to block all functions for the given file `test.lua` correct? Does `jit.off(true, true)` not fill your need? http://luajit.org/ext_jit.html When jit.off is used this way it can turn off jit for a whole module.

Answer (score 2):

jit.off(true, true) will disable jit compiling for the current script. jit.off(function) will disable jit compiling for a specific function.